# Python: Round off negative number to the nearest upper 0.5

Tags: python, algorithm, math, rounding, negative-number

I want to round negative numbers to the nearest upper 0.5 using python.

For example :

```
-1.2 => -1
-0.8 => -0.5
```

etc

if I use

```
round(number * 2) / 2.0
```

it returns me the nearest lower 0.5 (for example : -2.4 returns me -2.5 and i want -2.0)

How can I do that in python ?

Comment: Does ceil(num*2)/2 work

Comment: Yes, works perfectly !  Thank you all for your answers and implication !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use`ceil` method of `math` to get what you want. Use `floor` if using positive numbers.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil((-0.8*2))/2
-0.5
>>> math.ceil((-1.2*2))/2
-1.0
>>> math.ceil((-2.4*2))/2
-2.0
```